# C++ Reference to inhereting child in abstract parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

Imagine the childs Dog and Cat of Animal with these copy constructors:

```
class Animal
{
   public:
   Animal(??? other);
}

class Dog : Animal
{
   public:
   Dog(Dog& other);
}

class Cat : Animal
{
   public:
   Cat(Cat& other);
}
```

What do I have to write for the `???` in the parent Animal class to allow the following constructors:

```
Cat cat(otherCat);
Dog dog(otherDog);
```

But not these as it would be with `Animal&`:

```
Cat cat(otherDog);
Dog dog(otherCat);
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have no constructor accepting animal in super class? Then only sub class constructors will be called

Comment: first of all, if you are dealing with C++ you missed a `:` after the `public` keyword. Secondly, you can just put `otherAnimal` there, since constructors are not inherited

Comment: If you give `Dog` a `Cat` what do you want to end up with?

Comment: @TylerNichols the idea is that i want to require each subclass of Animal to have such a copy constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just take a `Animal&`/`const Animal&` in `Animal`'s copy constructor.  Doing so wont make `Cat cat(otherDog);` work as only `Cat`'s copy constructor is considered. If you uncomment `Dog dog(cat);` the following code won't compile.

```
class Animal
{
   public:
   Animal(const Animal& other) {}
   Animal() {}
};

class Dog : Animal
{
   public:
   Dog(const Dog& other) : Animal(other) {}
   Dog() {}
};


class Cat : Animal
{
   public:
   Cat(const Cat& other) : Animal(other) {}
   Cat() {}
};

int main()
{
    Cat cat;
    Cat other(cat);
    //Dog dog(cat);
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa11b3e515b40906)</kbd>

Comment: Does this only apply to constructors? What if i have a function speakTo(otherAnimal) so cats can only talk to cats and dogs to dogs?

Comment: @Schokocrossi Yes-ish, constructors are not inherited and if you write a function with the same name in a derived class as the base class that derived class function will hide the base class one.